# aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 404 при работе с tg local api server

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, api, сервер

Пытаюсь запустить telegram local api server но при выполнении действий в боте появляется ошибка:

```
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 404, message='Not Found', url=URL('http://localhost:8081/file/bot6104913242:AAF0yY8otDnLtdb94aaqCaQgT69J-v9yfI4/C:%5CTMP%5Cdata%5C6104913242~AAF0yY8otDnLtdb94aaqCaQgT69J-v9yfI4%5Cvideos%5Cfile_2.mp4')
```

Менял ip, порты, пути файлов не понимаю в чем проблема